# Cant run composer install because a mismatch in PHP version

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have PHP version `8.1.5` as I'm writing this and I'm trying to experiment with older github repo like [trix tutorial](https://github.com/amaelftah/laravel-trix-tutorial) for example and a problem occurs when I tried to run `composer install` an error that said

```
    Your lock file does not contain a compatible set of packages. Please run composer update.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires php ^7.2.5 but your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 2
    - doctrine/inflector is locked to version 1.3.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/inflector 1.3.1 requires php ^7.1 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 3
    - doctrine/lexer is locked to version 1.2.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - doctrine/lexer 1.2.0 requires php ^7.2 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 4
    - dragonmantank/cron-expression is locked to version v2.3.0 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - dragonmantank/cron-expression v2.3.0 requires php ^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
  Problem 5
    - laravel/framework is locked to version v7.2.1 and an update of this package was not requested.
    - laravel/framework v7.2.1 requires php ^7.2.5 -> your php version (8.1.5) does not satisfy that requirement.
...
```

I certainly don't want to downgrade my PHP version is there a way to upgrade those packages to be compatible with my PHP version?

so far I've tried

change my `composer.json` file

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=8.1.5",
        ...
    },
```

and

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.5",
        ...
    },
```

and running both `composer install` and `composer update php --with-all-dependencies`

Comment: Why not use `composer update`  to install more recent versions of your packages? But this is only possible if your require package versions that are compatible with PHP 8. As  you haven't provided more details, it's difficult to provide more help

Comment: Also, keep in mind that Laravel v7 is no longer supported since March 2021, so you should not only update your packages to the latest available patch versions, but also perform some larger upgrades

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Composer's `--ignore-platform-reqs` switch to install packages. It will install packages without complaining, but it's not guaranteed that your code will run.